# TStringList.ValueFromIndex[Y] := '' удаляет строку?

Tags: delphi

Столкнулся с чем-то, очень похожим на баг компилятора. Delphi 10.2 Tokyo.
Поясняю на примере:

```
var L:TStringList;
begin
  L:=TStringList.Create;
  L.Append('Name=Value');
  L.ValueFromIndex[0]:='';
  ShowMessage (L.Text); // <-выдает пустую строку
  L.Free;
```

То есть присваивание '' на Values['XXX'] или ValuesfromIndex[Y] производит эффект, аналогичный Delete (Y).

Это действительно баг компилятора или я конкретно туплю ?

Comment: ну, вы затерли строку по индексу [0], и т.к. в StringList больше ничего нет, вот он и выводит пустую строку.

Comment: 1. Я затер не строку, а Values - часть строки после =
2. Даже если представить, что я затер всю строку, она должна остаться (но быть пустой). А L.Count выводит 0. Строки вообще нет.

Answer (score 4):

В коде `TStrings` (родителе `TStringList`), написано ровно следующее:

```
procedure TStrings.SetValueFromIndex(Index: Integer; const Value: string);
begin
  if Value <> '' then
  begin
    if Index < 0 then Index := Add('');
    Put(Index, Names[Index] + NameValueSeparator + Value);
  end
  else
    if Index >= 0 then Delete(Index);
end;
```

и

```
procedure TStrings.SetValue(const Name, Value: string);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  I := IndexOfName(Name);
  if Value <> '' then
  begin
    if I < 0 then I := Add('');
    Put(I, Name + NameValueSeparator + Value);
  end else
  begin
    if I >= 0 then Delete(I);
  end;
end;
```

Так что поведение определенно такое и указано: *"присваивание '' на Values['XXX'] или ValuesfromIndex[Y] производит эффект, аналогичный Delete (Y)."*

Comment: Все-таки я вот тоже попробовал сейчас и недоумение ТСа разделяю - почему же нельзя присвоить пустое значение существующему ключу? Ведь добавить пару ключ-значение с изначально пустым значением в TStringList можно (`TStringList.AddPair('name','')`). Нелогично как-то получается.

Comment: Таковы "правила игры" и сейчас, с тоннами легаси кода, никто в Делфи это поведение менять не будет. Остается только простить и принять.

Comment: KadafiVSC, так если вы потом считаете значение по ключу: Values['XXX'] - то вам вернется пустая строка. Как и для изначально отсутствующего ключа. Какая разница как при этом работает черный ящик, в нем отсутствует запись или она есть, но равна пустой строке?

Comment: @Pit да в принципе я с вами согласен, что разницы особой нет. Просто в одном случае (при вызове `TStrings.SetValue('Name','')`) никаких данных о ключе не остается, а в другом (при вызове `TStrings.AddPair('Name','')`) ключ с пустым значением все-таки появляется. Меня смущает только то, что 2 разных метода одного класса интерпретируют отсутствие значения в переданных параметрах совершенно по-разному.